# Trying to make a table in c++, having trouble

Tags: c++, iostream

So I'm new to c++, and I'm working on making a table using for loops.

I've been having trouble for the for loop to have the starting column, row, and `calcWind` values all in one loop. So I decided to break it down into 2 parts.

The first for loop, places all starting values of the row. The next for loop places the columns values, and then inserts the row # and column # into the function I made to calculate wind speed.

I'm now having trouble for `Calcwind` to show the actual calculations on the console screen.

Thanks again for the help in advance :)

[image: Here's what the console image should look like, I'm just laying down the values with my code for now.]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double calcWind(double temperature, double windSpeed)
{
    double wind = 0;
    wind = 35.74 + (.621 * temperature) - (35.75 * pow(windSpeed, 0.16)) + (.4275 * temperature * pow(windSpeed, .16));
    wind = nearbyint(wind);
    return wind;
}

int main()
{
    int rows = 40;
    int columns = 5;

    for (rows; rows >= -30; rows = rows - 5)
    {
        cout << setw(6) << rows;
    }

    for (columns; columns <= 60; columns = columns + 5)
    {
        cout << endl << columns;
        for (rows; rows >= -30; rows = rows - 5)
        {
            cout << setw(6) << calcWind(rows, columns);
        }
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::system("pause");` is pretty dangerous, just so you know.

Comment: after the first loop, your variable `rows` equals to `-30` already.

Comment: Please elaborate of your _"trouble"_. That's pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

Here you create `rows`:

```
int rows = 40;
```

You then keep subtracting 5 until it's under -30 (in the first loop):

```
for (rows; rows >= -30; rows = rows - 5)
```

Then, in the loop where you print the output of `calcWind`, `rows` is still equal to -35. The condition `rows >= -30` fails on the first iteration and never runs `calcWind` or prints the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

double calcWind(double temperature, double windSpeed)
{
    double wind = 0;
    wind = 35.74 + (.621 * temperature) - (35.75 * pow(windSpeed, 0.16)) + (.4275 * temperature * pow(windSpeed, .16));
    wind = nearbyint(wind);
    return wind;
}

int main()
{
//    int rows = 40;
//    int columns = 5;

    for (int rows = 40; rows >= -30; rows = rows - 5)
    {
        cout << setw(6) << rows;
    }

    for (int columns = 5; columns <= 60; columns = columns + 5)
    {
        cout << endl << columns;
        for (int rows = 40; rows >= -30; rows = rows - 5)
        {
            cout << setw(6) << calcWind(rows, columns);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\nPress any key to continue. . .\n";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```